# Cant locate desired local directory while using SCP on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, scp

I'm trying to copy a local directory to the root directory of my 1and1 server. I'm on a mac and I've ssh'ed into the server just fine. I looked online and saw numerous examples all along the same lines. I tried:

```
 scp -r ~/Desktop/Projects/resume  u67673257@aimhighprogram.com:/
```

The result in my terminal was:
[image]

I'm not sure where `Kuden/homepages/29/d401405832/htdocs` came from, I thought the `~` would take me to the macbook user directory

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not sure if I'm just missing something simple.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scp, issue the command on your Mac, don't SSH into 1and1.

The error message is telling you that ~/Desktop/Projects/resume is not on the 1and1 server, which you know - because you're working to put it there.

More ...

```
scp myfile myuser@myserver:~/mypath/myuploadedfile
```

You would read this as:

scp **myfile** to **myserver**, logging in as **myuser** and place it under the **mypath** directory of the **myuser** account, with the name **myuploadedfile**